# Scraping a webpage using BeautifulSoup4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to print the content of a news article using BeautifulSoup4.

The URL is: [Link](http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/People-showing-monumental-patience-queuing-up-for-a-better-India-says-Venkaiah/article16447029.ece)

The current code which I have is as follows which gives the desired output:

```
page = requests.get('http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/People-showing-monumental-patience-queuing-up-for-a-better-India-says-Venkaiah/article16447029.ece')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


article_text = ""
table = soup.find_all("div",{ "id": "content-body-14266949-16447029"})                              

for element in table:
    article_text += ''.join(element.find_all(text = True)) + "\n\n"

print(article_text)
```

However, the problem is I want to scrape multiple pages and each of them has a different content body number in the format xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx (2 blocks of 8 digits.)

I tried replacing the soup.find_all command with regex as:

> table = soup.find_all(text=re.compile("content-body-........-........"))

but this gives an error:

> AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Can anybody guide me to what needs to be done?

Thank you.

Comment: You want all the links that is a href's to get printed as output right ?

Comment: No. I am trying to print the text of the article.

soup.find_text() gives me the whole text while the content I need is embedded in multiple <p> elements in  a <div> with the id content-body-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions should be fine! Try

```
table = soup.find_all("div",{ "id": re.compile('content-body-*')})
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. soup.find('div',attrs={"id":re.compile("content-body-........-........")}).find_all("p") worked.

Answer (score 2):

you can use extract content by using lxml
lxml library allow you use xpath to extract content from html

```
from lxml import etree
selector=etree.HTML(pageText)
article_text=selector.xpath('//div[@class="article-block-multiple live-snippet"]/div[1]')[0].text
```

i don't use BeautifulSoup.I think you can use BeautifulSoup like this

```
table = soup.find_all("div",{ "class": "article-block-multiple live-snippet"]"})
```

then use find child element ,find the first div element

Answer (score 1):

Another approach may be with css selector. Selectors are clean and to the point. You might give it a try as well. Just change the "url" with your concerning link.

```
import requests ; from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(res,"html.parser")

for item in soup.select("div[id^=content-body-] p"):
    print(item.text)
```